# Strange error is showing when trying to open partner security portal with primary partner community user

Tags: checkmarx, security-scanner, source-scanner

> https://security.secure.force.com/sourcescanner/ is down for
> maintenance
>
> Sorry for the inconvenience. We'll be back shortly. Please email us if
> you need to get in touch.

[image]

This error is shown when I try to login to partner security portal with my primary partner community user. While if I login with Dev Hub user, it works ok and doesn't throw an error, which is strange.

Is there any reason why it is failing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After I opened a Salesforce support case, I was told to open the following link https://login.salesforce.com/services/auth/sso/00D30000000JsbiEAC/Chimera?site=https://security.secure.force.com/chimera

When I opened that link and granted access, the error has gone

Comment: Ran into this same issue. I am trying to access the security portal. It's giving me same error page. Tried the above chimera link as well, this is also redirecting me towards same error page.

The mail link is not even working on that page.

Comment: this is strange. How you tried to open the link in a different browser or incognito window?

Comment: I was able to resolve it by, connecting my package development org in Partner Portal. Security portal was not allowing me log in with partner salesforce org credentials, but once I linked the partner developer edition org on Partner Portal and tried to login with those credentials. I was good. One more thing to  keep in mind is check the login URL, it should be `login.salesforce.com` else it'll redirect to My Domain URL of your recent SF org.

Answer (score -3):

Please try:

- cleaning your browser cache
- remove all salesforce cookies (search cookies: "force") - remove all
- login to your PBO

Only now you can login to your Salesforce Security Portal.

Hope it works! :)

Comment: Well, this doesn't answer my question and actually I have contacted Salesforce support and they provided me a solution which I posted as an answer